# How to get product id in CartItemInterface API response?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, response

When we use this API

`https://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/items`

to get Cart Items its gives response like

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [item_id] => 1234
        [sku] => 123456789          
        [qty] => 1
        [name] => Test Product
        [price] => 123
        [product_type] => simple
        [quote_id] => 1234
    )
```

)

I need to get the product id with that response like .

```
     Array
  (
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [item_id] => 1234
        [sku] => 123456789
        [product_id] => 1234
        [qty] => 1
        [name] => Test Product
        [price] => 123
        [product_type] => simple
        [quote_id] => 1234
    )
```

)

I know if we edit this file `CartItemInterface.php` and add these lines

```
 const KEY_PRODUCT_ID = 'product_id';
 public function getProductId();
 public function setProductId($productId);
```

and edit `Item.php` add these functions

```
  public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::KEY_PRODUCT_ID);
    }

  public function setProductId($productId)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_PRODUCT_ID, $productId);
    }
```

will retun automatically. But I want to implement this in properway. without edit original files.

How to I achieve this.

Comment: after fetching the collection you can modify the array.

Comment: I also faced this.

Comment: IN response array.

Comment: Yes, In cartItemInterfacer, they does not return product_id But we can get from quote_item, am getting confusion to override [click here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item.php)

Comment: I am not suggesting to edit in CORE files :)

Comment: Just change the response array, it will work.

Comment: Yes, you  have details at quote item but as data provide class does not getter function on this field so, you cannot get that field  value

Comment: May be override by `quote_item` you get   but be honest i am not sure about  it

Comment: @Adityashah can you please tell me the file name

Comment: Here, item_id is same as product_id so if you want it in $respose array then you can modify the array with Iteam_id to product_id.

this is what i did in my api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the Product id from this API .

As per as, you can get those value which is defined at there respective interfacer [`CartItemInterface` .](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/CartItemInterface.php),

So you have to build own API for archive this task.